# Right way to manage components functionality in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found on React documentation page, that the technique using the right way React can be based on Single responsibility principle, that is a component should do one thing only.
I've already made a simple `Gameboard`, which includes input, score random generated number and a condition. All the calculations and presentations are made in `Gameboard` component.
Now I would like split up my application in to different components. What is the proper way to do so?
One way as I thought is to make a different components like so: `Score`, `Input`, `RandomNumber`. But I'm pretty lost. I make a `Score` component, in that component I'm displaying data and updating the `score` state. So how should I pass this data to my parent `Gameboard` component? With a callback function?

Or should I just make a variable in `Gameboard` of my `score` value, all the incrementation(functionality of `score: this.state.score + 1` should be done   in `Score` component, update the `score` in `Score` component and send the updated data to `Gameboard` component?

Comment: Does the Gameboard need to know the score? Do you want the 'Score' component to just display the score or also update it?

Comment: I want to make the condition checking in Gameboard, so I'm pretty sure Gameboard should know about current user score. I'm thinking to make new Components of Input, Score and RandomNumber, and place them in Gameboard component like so: <Input/>, <Score/>. So that there won't be that much code in Gameboard component. Or should I make another component to check condition if a user won the game? To summarize, I don't know if I should increment scores state in Gameboard component or in a Score component

Comment: Honestly it's hard to say without knowing literally everything you're trying to do. I think you should play around and see what works.

Comment: Its sensible to divide components into presentation based or  ones which have the logic and hold the data. I have found that having the  components which have the logic and data are higher up the hierarchy and the presentation components are lower down closer to (if not the) leaf level. However sometimes it can be handy if something closer to leaf level is responsible for its own logic (e.g. determining what Icon it should be displaying based on a switch statement, vs calculating this 4 levels up and passing it down). To further extract logic you can use react hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extremely simple example where the state of the score is stored in the Gameboard, but is to be displayed and possibly added to by the Scoreboard

```
class Gameboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      score: 1
    }
  }
  
  add() {
    const newScore = this.state.score + 1;
    this.setState({score:newScore});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Scoreboard score={this.state.score} onAdd={this.add.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Scoreboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <h1>{this.props.score}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAdd}>add</button>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Gameboard />, mountNode);
```

You can input that code into [this site](https://jscomplete.com/playground) to see it work.

Comment: Thank you for an example. I'm pretty sure if I place a condition checking, whether the score should be updated or not, with a score incrementation  inside Gameboard component like you did, its no longer based on a Single Responsibility principle